# Как проверить состоит ли пользователь в чужой телеграм группе или канале?

Tags: c#, telegram

Уже все обыскал, не могу найти способ как проверить принадлежность юзера к определенному каналу или группе. Очень нужно!

Comment: очень удивлюсь если такое возможно, скорее всего это конфиденциальная информация

Comment: Данный вопрос следует закрыть, потому что не соответствует тематике сайта